# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:58971 from chrome not reachable

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux-2, undetected-chromedriver

I am running the following Python script in AWS EC2:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc


uc_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
uc_options.add_argument("--headless=new")

driver = uc.Chrome(options = uc_options, version_main = 114)
```

My undetected_chromedriver version is 3.5 and google-chrome version is 114.0.5735.198. I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 8, in <module>     driver = uc.Chrome(options = uc_options, version_main = 114)   File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 446, in __init__     keep_alive=keep_alive,   File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 54, in __init__     self.keep_alive,   File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__     options=self.options,   File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 206, in __init__     self.start_session(capabilities)   File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 675, in start_session     capabilities   File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 291, in start_session     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]   File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 346, in execute     self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:35551 from chrome not reachable Stacktrace: #0 0x5609f85f04e3 <unknown> #1 0x5609f831fb00 <unknown> #2 0x5609f830d436 <unknown> #3 0x5609f834c9be <unknown> #4 0x5609f8344884 <unknown> #5 0x5609f8383ccc <unknown> #6 0x5609f838347f <unknown> #7 0x5609f837ade3 <unknown> #8 0x5609f83502dd <unknown> #9 0x5609f835134e <unknown> #10 0x5609f85b03e4 <unknown> #11 0x5609f85b43d7 <unknown> #12 0x5609f85beb20 <unknown> #13 0x5609f85b5023 <unknown> #14 0x5609f85831aa <unknown> #15 0x5609f85d96b8 <unknown> #16 0x5609f85d9847 <unknown> #17 0x5609f85e9243 <unknown> #18 0x7f65c19f744b start_thread
```

Could someone please help me understand the issue and how can I resolve it?

I am new to running python code in Linux machine. The same code is running perfectly fine in my windows laptop. I have tried a lot searching over the internet but not able to figure out anything.